# Pulling/Pushing submodule commits using git-gui

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-gui

I spent some time breaking up a rather large and cluttered codebase into smaller more targeted projects and while doing so I gathered all of the shared code between the projects and pushed those into a separate repo with the intent of using it as a git submodule. I'm fairly comfortable with the command line so I've been setting all this up using that, but when I started writing some documentation to help out some coworkers with this setup and procedures I couldn't figure how to update their local repo's submodule. I know this can be accomplished on the command line with

*git submodule update --remote --merge*.

Is this possible to do within git-gui?